# static template functions in a class

Tags: c++, class, templates, static, typename

How do I make the following function inside a class and then access this function from main?
My class is just a collection of a bunch of static functions.

```
template<typename T> double foo(vector<T> arr);
```

Comment: This is what I tried... Except it is placed in an ordinary class

Comment: Since your class is just a collection of static functions, perhaps a `namespace` would be better?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Define the function in the .h file.

Works fine for me

a.h

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class A {
public:
template< typename T>
    static double foo( vector<T> arr );

};

template< typename T>
double A::foo( vector<T> arr ){ cout << arr[0]; }
```

main.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A a;
    vector<int> arr;
    arr.push_back(1);
    A::foo<int> ( arr );
}
```

Comment: It works now for me.. interesting and strange... I think visual studio is whack!! hahaha

Comment: every time when you declare templates, define them in a header file and it'll be OK then ))

Comment: You don't want to have using statements in header files: "using namespace std;"  Use "std::vector<T>" instead.

Comment: I get an error: E0245 a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object.

Comment: @James did you declare the method as `static` or did you forget the keyword

Comment: I hope that if I put template stanzas  per function then the template type could be deduced when calls are made. Am I getting it right?

Answer (score 7):

You make a template class:

```
template<typename T>
class First
{
public:
    static  double foo(vector<T> arr) {};
};
```

Also note that you should pass `vector` by reference, or in your case, also `const` reference would do the same.

```
template<typename T>
class First
{
public:
    static  double foo(const vector<T>& arr) {};
};
```

You can then call the function like:

```
First<MyClass>::foo(vect);
```

Comment: How do I call that function from main? I am getting a strange error after I call my function like this: ClassName<double>::foo(arr)

Comment: Got some unnecessary semicolons there.